# MYSQL query issue with UPDATE

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
UPDATE people 
SET column1 = (
    SELECT if(r.rand BETWEEN 103 AND 109, 110, r.rand)
    FROM ( SELECT floor(8+rand()*113) rand ) r
)
```

However, it sets the SAME random number to every row. How can I change it in order to give a different value to every row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem comes from the subquery, if you could simplify your assignment like the following:

```
UPDATE people 
SET column1 = floor(8+rand()*113)
```

It would work the way you expect: each row has assigned a different random number. However the subquery returns a single value that is assigned to all the rows.

I guess that if you can't simplify the logic to remove the scalar subquery, you may have to write a stored procedure or a short program to do what you want.

Comment: OR just run your query followed by UPDATE people SET column1 = 110 WHERE column1 BETWEEN 103 AND 109?